# How to select from and to date range from datepicker in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, datepicker, components, angular2-forms, datetimepicker

I'm working on angular 2 component where I have two `datepicker` as shown below.
Can select both date & time.

filter.component.html

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label>From</label>
      <angular2-date-picker (onDateSelect)="onDate1($event)" [(ngModel)]="date1" [settings]="settings"></angular2-date-picker>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label>To</label>
      <angular2-date-picker (onDateSelect)="onDate2($event)" [(ngModel)]="date2" [settings]="settings"></angular2-date-picker>
    </div>       
  </div>
```

And here is my filter.component.ts

```
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

private date1: Date = new Date();
private date2: Date = new Date();
settings = {
    bigBanner: true,
    timePicker: true,
    format: 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a'
}

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {

}

onDate1($event){
    this.date1;
    this.date2;

    let instance = this.date1;
    let date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+0);
    this.date2.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);


}

}
```

I have two `datepicker` called **From** & **To** in html file. I want to select date range where when I select a date from one `datepicker` I should be able to select from next date in another `datepicker`. I was trying JQuery code but its not working.

I'm new to Angular 2. I know exactly how it works in JavaScript but I don't have any idea on Angular 2. I'm not even getting any answers when I searched.

Comment: whats the output of $event ?

Comment: I'm getting the date & time which I have selected from `datepicker`.
Ex: Thu Jan 18 2018 15:35:40

Comment: just try   onDate1($event){
    this.date1 = this.date2;
}

Comment: and check if date of second date picker is changed or not ??

Comment: Its not working